# makefiles implicit rules says file up to date but file doesn't even exist

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I tried to use make's implicit rules to compile simple C file.

```
# -*- MakeFile -*-

new.o: new.c
```

Output:

```
make: 'new.o' is up to date.
```

But `new.o` doesn't exist at this point. But I added another rule and it worked as intended.

```
# -*- MakeFile -*-

new.o: new.c

clean:
    rm -f new.o
```

Output:

```
cc    -c -o new.o new.c
```

Now it ran the command as expected. Does it require to have at least two recipes to work or is it something very obvious that I missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a silly mistake by adding extra <del>newline</del> **TAB** character below my implicit recipe. Removing the extra <del>newline</del> **TAB** character solves the problem

Edited makefile

```
# -*- MakeFile -*-

new.o: new.c
```

Output:

```
cc    -c -o new.o new.c
```

Comment: I posted this as answer since I couldn't find how to resolve this issue and couldn't relevant SO answer. Hope this answer helps the future readers.

Comment: It's not the case that "a newline" will cause the behavior you're seeing.  You can have as many _EMPTY_ lines at the end of a file as you like.  What you must have done was have an extra line **containing a TAB character**.  TAB characters are special to make (you can google to read about this).

Comment: @MadScientist Thank you. You're right. It's the tab that triggered this behavior. I'll make appropriate changes to the answer. Or you can add an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: That's OK, you've got it covered :)